# How to initialize initdb in fedora postgresql

Tags: postgresql, fedora

I was installed postgresql on fedora 20 using rpm packages. i was manually downloaded the packages which were required for postgres those packages are as follows:

> libxslt-1.1.28-5.fc20.x86_64.rpm postgresql-9.3.1-2.fc20.x86_64.rpm
>   postgresql93-9.3.4-1PGDG.f20.x86_64.rpm
>   postgresql93-contrib-9.3.4-1PGDG.f20.x86_64.rpm
>   postgresql93-libs-9.3.4-1PGDG.f20.x86_64.rpm
>   postgresql93-server-9.3.4-1PGDG.f20.x86_64.rpm
>   postgresql-libs-9.3.1-2.fc20.x86_64.rpm uuid-1.6.2-26.el7.x86_64.rpm

and i was installed those packages like this.

```
[root@fedorarpmpostgres ~]# rpm -ivh libxslt-1.1.28-5.fc20.x86_64.rpm
```

Output

```
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]

    package libxslt-1.1.28-5.fc20.x86_64 is already installed

so its already installed ok now i'm successfull in stalling all this packages. now how can i 
install initdb

i  tried like this way but i got this error.

[root@fedorarpmpostgres ~]# /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/initdb --encoding=UTF8 --
```

Output:

```
pgdata=/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/

initdb: cannot be run as root


Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

one thing i was to inform you is i'm success in installing postgres through yum but i need postgres installation through rpm only like the way i did above

could any body help me how to initialize initdb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With your root user, if you haven't set the postgres user password, which is not set by default, do a su postgres and you should be able to do a initdb.